# Apiary - Howto change the format of cURL call

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

In Apiary, the cURL call to production by default is :

https://example.com/v1/findBrandCat?matchstring=&interestType=

I have to make a call in following structure:

https://example.com/v1/findBrandCat/matchstringVALUE/interestTypeVALUE

How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URI template for the API resource can be defined as follows:

```
# GET /v1/findBrandCat/{matchstringValue}/{interestTypeValue}

+ Parameters
    + matchstringValue: (required, string)
    + interestTypeValue: (required, string)

+ Response 200 (application/json)
```